# Python VkApiError: 15. Acces denied: no access to call this method

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Создал Standalone приложение, получил токен с помощью

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6430985&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,messages,email,notifications,stats,ads,offline,docs,pages,stats,notifications&response_type=token
```

Но, при попытке запроса к медоту docs.getMessagesUploadServer возникает ошибка:

```
vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 15. Access denied: no access to call this method. requests_params = {"oauth":"1", "method":"docs.getMessagesUploadServer", "v":"5.73", "type":"audio_message", "peer_id": "2000000000142"}
```

Сам код:

```
import vk
import requests

files = {"tts":open('/home/root1/Загрузки/tts.ogg', "rb")}
session = vk.Session(access_token="Censored")
vk_api = vk.API(session)
upload_urls = vk_api.docs.getMessagesUploadServer(v="5.73",type="audio_message",peer_id="2000000000142")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в scope почему-то дважды docs повторяется. И pages тоже. Нужно чтобы каждое право встречалось только один раз.

Так как права работают на битовых масках(https://vk.com/dev/permissions), два раза docs это +131072 и еще раз +131072 к общей сумме, получается +262144, а это уже право groups. Которое, кстати, вы тоже запрашиваете, поэтому там тоже получается сдвиг и вообще вся маска прав едет.